# Thorntail basic authentication

Tags: security, wildfly, thorntail

I'm migrating a WildFly 15 JEE application to Thorntail 2.4.0.

In WildFly I could create users with the bin/add-user.bat utility assigning roles to them (Admin in my case).

In web.xml the restriction would be defined to allow only those users to access.

```
<!-- Security -->
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Restricted Access</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

How can I create similar users with Thorntail?

Comment: Almost the same question was asked a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430506/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-add-application-users-in-a-thorntail-wildfly-server

Comment: Thanks I didn't see that one!